# Python: help menu doesn't show all options when using parse_known_args()

Tags: python

I went through a "little" issue using python argument parser, I've created a parser like shown below:

```
parser = ArgumentParser(formatter_class=ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)

parser.add_argument('-l', '--log-level', help="log level")
parser.add_argument('-o', '--out-dir', help="output directory")

args, remaining = parser.parse_known_args()

outpu_dir = args.out_dir

parser.add_argument('-f', '--log-file', help = "log file directory")

args = parser.parse_args()
```

and the problem is that when calling the program with --help option, arguments added after parse_known_args() are not listed in the menu, I checked other topics related to this, but my case is a bit different! could any one give a help here please ?

Answer (score 0):

**Any** code which is below the call to `parse_known_args` will not execute at all.

```py
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-a')
parser.parse_known_args()
1/0
```

When running with `--help` this generates

```
usage: main.py [-h] [-a A]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -a A

Process finished with exit code 0
```

and not a `ZeroDivisionError` exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can work around it by adding the `help` option **after** all the other args have been added & you've parsed the known args.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser, ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter, SUPPRESS

# don't add help right now
parser = ArgumentParser(formatter_class=ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter, add_help=False)

parser.add_argument('-l', '--log-level', help="log level")
parser.add_argument('-o', '--out-dir', help="output directory")

args, remaining = parser.parse_known_args()

outpu_dir = args.out_dir

parser.add_argument('-f', '--log-file', help="log file directory")
# add help later, when all other args have been added
parser.add_argument('-h', '--help', action='help', default=SUPPRESS,
                    help='Show this help message and exit.')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Which results in:

```
(venv) ➜  python main.py --help
usage: main.py [-l LOG_LEVEL] [-o OUT_DIR] [-f LOG_FILE] [-h]

optional arguments:
  -l LOG_LEVEL, --log-level LOG_LEVEL
                        log level (default: None)
  -o OUT_DIR, --out-dir OUT_DIR
                        output directory (default: None)
  -f LOG_FILE, --log-file LOG_FILE
                        log file directory (default: None)
  -h, --help            Show this help message and exit.
```

But it's much better if you can restructure your code to add all the argusments first before doing any parsing (i.e. avoid the call to `parse_known_aergs` before any other `add_argument` calls)